# NSResponder chain being broken after i remove / insert views

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

It appears that when i remove subviews from my NSViewController main view, responder chain gets modified and new views never receive the first responder.

View controller is inside popover. There is search field on top, and custom views below (search results). When i show popover i can use tab to go to the custom views. But if i search for some phrase search results are changed and tab no longer works.

Any idea if there is way to 'fix' the responder chain ?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what you're doing, since obviously a great many apps dynamically remove and add views without any problem with the responder chain.

Comment: Do you mean the responder chain (`nextResponder`) or the key view loop/tab order (`nextKeyView`)?

Comment: @Willeke i mean tab loop order yeah. I have search field and some custom views below, when i change search phase i remove views below, and after that tab does not work.

Comment: Google for "nspopover key view loop"

Comment: @Wilkeke thank you, first result looks like what's going on: http://mikeabdullah.net/nspopover-key-view-loop.html autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop in popover is false by default. Could you post an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from Mike Abdullah

[NSPopover: Key View Loop](http://mikeabdullah.net/nspopover-key-view-loop.html)

> While poking around NSPopover, one discovery has slightly surprised me: The NSWindow that AppKit creates behind the scenes for the popover has autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop turned off. That can have slightly odd consequences if you’re dynamically changing the content or layout of the popover, since AppKit won’t take those changes into account.
>
> (If you need a quick explanation, The Key View Loop defines what happens when you hit the tab key, which control the focus moves to)
>
> Since we don’t own the window in question, I’m a little hesitant to turn autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop on. Instead, it’s generally pretty simple to call recalculateKeyViewLoop on the window after you’ve made a change.

Comment: 5 Years later and this solution `recalculateKeyViewLoop` was the only way I could get NSTextFields within NSViews hosted by a containerView to activate and work correctly when they were swapped.